# If referer url includes xx in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make if statement in htaccess, If referer includes **search?q=**

I came up with this example, if referer urls which include ebay.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?.*(-|.)ebay(-|.).*$ [NC,OR]
```

How can I change it to  **search?q=** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} search?q= [NC]
```

Comment: That's a little late answer :) but yeah that's what I was searching, thanks!